# Div Missing In Custom Loop Query

Tags: php, loop, query-posts

I'm using a customized php code for my wordpress loop. The code is designed the break the post up to be styled differently via html & css. The code is also designed so that I can add div blocks in between the post.

See the photo below for an example of the code's use.

Here is the code below that I am using.

https://gist.github.com/mihadaiko/dc314a845f807c16d19db8c842ed7a75

My Problem is that the DIV that's suppose to come before the last 10 post is not showing up. I don't believe that it's an issue with my css file, but if you need those files too here they are.

Full Index.php file with HTML/PHP

https://gist.github.com/mihadaiko/c4a9ef6f19c4b57cb239971d5e21d594

Full CSS File

https://gist.github.com/mihadaiko/4da7e1a4b8b9488a676ec175713a43f0

Here is a photo of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

The problem is that the DIV that has the Jeep AD is not being displayed. At all. Can anyone help me to find a solution as to why this is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this code:

```
elseif (17 < $count && $count <= 27 && $paged === 1) :
       if ($count === 10) echo 'DIV/CONTENT BEFORE THE NEXT 10 POST GOES HERE';
```

The first conditional fails when `10 === $count` and so the second conditional can never succeed.

As your while loop executes (in a structure that WordPress calls The Loop, calling function `the_post()` to advance through the list of posts you are processing to generate this web page) `$count` is incremented as a way of keeping track of which post the code is working on.

When Bernie Sanders is being processed `$count === 1`, when we get to Drake's Album `$count === 4` and so on until every post on the page has been rendered.  The code doesn't have sections of posts with their own counts, there's just a count from the top, so your Jeep ad needs to be inserted when `$count === 15` according to your picture.  I'm not completely sure, as you have a block of 6 posts labelled as "next 9."

Comment: so how can i fix this problem @andy macaulay-brook

Comment: That depends on what you intend those nested conditionals to do.  Is $count just a count of how many posts you are up to in your loop?

Comment: I think I may have a misunderstanding of the counts property. I thought that $count === was to equal to how many post to show. I hired a developer to develop this. I have some understanding if php coding but not this much. I'm trying to learn the best I can.

Comment: I thought that 17 equaled the number of post already above, 27 represents 10 more post 17+10 = 27 and the $count === i was suppose to put 10. I would love some explaining on this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the history and your position, it helps when framing responses.  I've added to my answer.

Comment: How do I know/determine what numbers to choose. What numbers to put. for example the drake post `(1 < $count && $count <= 3` does that mean after the first post count up to 3 post. Also I know you said put `$count === 4` for the drake post but is 4 chosen because 1+3 = 4

Comment: Is `1 < $count && $count <= 3` the developer's code or yours?

Comment: Drake is the 4th post, after Bernie and the two posts next to him, so that's why $count is 4 at that point in the loop, yes.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you, You have been such a big help. I'm happy that I learned something new. You are a life saver @Andy